# Passing XML parameter to REST Endpoint

Tags: karate

We have a middleware REST service that is taking an XML response from one endpoint and passing it as a parameter to another.

This works in Karate using the following syntax:

```
Given url endpointURL
And param requestInput = '<?xml version="1.0" ?> <sampleResponseXML> <sampleField>COLA</sampleField> </sampleResponseXML>'
When method get
Then status 200
```

This gives the proper expected response.

I am looking to read the xml parameter from a file but it seems the escape parameters get messy and I have been unsuccessful with this. The endpoint is created with several extra escape characters and not formatted properly. Is there any method to possibly accomplish this?

```
Given url endpointURL
And param requestInput = read('param.xml')
When method get
Then status 200
```